# Need to get records using day between from day and to day

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysqli

How can I get records from database using only day name.  I have a column in the database which is `from_day` and `to_day`.

If I pass `Tue` then I need result where `from` is less `Tue` (like `Mon`), and `end` is greater (like `Wed`).

For example, if I pass `Tue` then I need records where the column should have `Mon` as `from_day` and `to_day` should be `Wed` or `Tue`.

I have tried this:

```sql
SELECT booking_times.* FROM booking_times WHERE 'Tue' BETWEEN
DATE_FORMAT(booking_times.from_day, 'D') AND
DATE_FORMAT(booking_times.to_day, 'D');
```

Comment: Can you share some of your related code with us ?

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please add table schema with some sample data & expected output. That'll be really helpful to answer your question.

Comment: You might want to use Carbon class (https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) along with Eloquent or Query Builder. I personally do that when having to deal with any datetime based conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try this one**

```
SELECT booking_times.* FROM booking_times WHERE DATE_FORMAT(booking_times.from_day, 'enter day') AND DATE_FORMAT(booking_times.to_day, 'enter to day');
```